# How to use numpy to operate on tensors in tensorflow lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a tensorflow graph that attempts to split an image into three single channel images.

```
input_image = tf.placeholder(name="input_image", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[512 * 512 *3])
feed_dict ={input_image:resized_image_data}

channel_image = tf.reshape(input_image, (512, 512, 3))
```

I slice the tensor, compute blur and then use  numpy's dstack on the "evaluated" tensors.
This works in tensorflow but tensorflow lite fails with "Can not allocate memory" error.

```
r,g,b = channel_image[:,:,0],channel_image[:,:,1],channel_image[:,:,2]

rtensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(r)
gtensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(g)
btensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(b)

rbatch = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(rtensor, axis=2), axis=0)
gbatch = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(gtensor, axis=2), axis=0)
bbatch = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(btensor, axis=2), axis=0)

rblur = tf.squeeze(blur(one_chan_kernel, strides, rbatch, 2), name="rblur")
gblur = tf.squeeze(blur(one_chan_kernel, strides, gbatch, 2), name="gblur")
bblur = tf.squeeze(blur(one_chan_kernel, strides, bbatch, 2), name="bblur")

result_np = np.dstack((rblur.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict), gblur.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict), bblur.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)))
result = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(result_np, name="result_tensor"), axis=0)
```

How can I use numpy to operate on the tensor results? 
I can not use tf.unstack and tf.stack since they are not currently implemented in tensorflow. lite

The logcat is:

> ```
>                                                                             --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> 07-02 11:20:36.486 6553-6553/camerafragment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: camerafragment, PID: 6553
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {camerafragment/camerafragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can not allocate memory for the interpreter
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3773)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3805)
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can not allocate memory for the interpreter
>                                                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.createInterpreter(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:63)
>                                                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:51)
>                                                                                       at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.(Interpreter.java:90)
>                                                                                       at camerafragment.MainActivity.initializeInference(MainActivity.java:230)
>                                                                                       at camerafragment.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:91)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7287)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3805) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 0):

Until recently stack and unstack weren't supported by TensorFlow Lite. The "cannot allocate memory" error is likely due to the fact that the conversion failed. If you try again using tensorflow's nightly it might work.